# How to get variable value after form submit on simple page?

Tags: octobercms

```
==
function onCheck()
{
   // It's simple page, not component, partial or controller
   // Therefore this syntax is right (according October docs)
   $this['myvar'] = "Hello";
}
==

<form class="dates" action="" method="POST" data-request="onCheck">
    <input type='text' class='date_inout' name="start" id='start'>
    <input type='text' class='date_inout' name="end" id='end'>
    <input type="submit" value="Подобрать">
</form>

<h1>{{ myvar }}</h1>
```

`myvar` isn't outputing. I need get `myvar` only after form submit, not `onStart` or `onInit`

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need output only after ajax then you need to do this

```php
==
function onCheck()
{
   $dates = post('start') . ' - ' . post('end');
   return ['#myvarContsiner' => "Hello " . $dates];
   //         ^ this id
}
==

<form class="dates" action="" method="POST" data-request="onCheck">
    <input type='text' class='date_inout' name="start" id='start'>
    <input type='text' class='date_inout' name="end" id='end'>
    <input type="submit" value="Подобрать">
</form>

<h1 id="myvarContsiner"></h1>
<!-- this id ^ -->
```

> Now when you hit `submit button` it will go to `onCheck` and return value `['#myvarContsiner' => "Hello " . $dates]` so basically `"Hello " . $dates` will be updated in `<h1 id="myvarContsiner"></h1>` as per **matching ID**.

and your  will show value as you return it from `onCheck`

if you have any doubt please comment.

Comment: Actually onCheck returns array (result of sql query). And I need get elements of array with {{ }}. How can I do it?

Comment: hope you'll help

Comment: if you can share your `onCheck` code i can help you